# search_term = voice input ,Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Hi  search_term = voice input ,it displays Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

```
 if mydb.is_connected():
            if there_exists(["what "]):
                search_term = voice_data.split("is")[-1]
                meaning = ('SELECT meaning FROM words')
                sql = f"SELECT '{meaning}' FROM words WHERE word = '{search_term}'"
                mycursor = mydb.cursor()
                mycursor.execute(sql, (meaning,))
                myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
                for meaning in myresult:
                    speak(meaning)
                else:
                    speak("i dont know")
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. Have you done any debugging? See also [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't see the second parameter in mycursor.execute(sql, (meaning,)) after meaning for search_term.

Comment: What should i write to theree?

Answer (score 0):

Because your are setting

```
search_term = voice_data.split("is")[-1]
meaning = ('SELECT meaning FROM words')
```

And

```
sql = f"SELECT '{meaning}' FROM words WHERE word = '{search_term}'"
```

execute function first parameter is the sql string, and second parameter, a list of sql parameters, in
mycursor.execute(sql, (meaning,))
you are trying to pass meaning var as parameter to execute, but no parameters are defined in your sql string.

Have a look at https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

You have to replace '{meaning}' and '{search_term}' by %s like in the doc above.

But if you do this, your query looks like SELECT SELECT meaning FROM words FROM words WHERE .... So up to you to replace meaning by what your are looking for.

If 'meaning' is a field of words, your slq string should be:

```
sql = "SELECT meaning FROM words WHERE word = '%s'"
```

and:

```
mycursor.execute(sql, (search_term))
```

It's better to use sql parameters than concatenate string for security issues